# Report Intervention, Auto or Manual

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssms

is there a way to use an SQL query to find out if an SSRS report is being Run Automatically or Manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the executionlog table to get this info. The RequestType column tells you if it was run interactively or not

```
select * from ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog e 
    join ReportServer.dbo.[Catalog] c on e.ReportID = c.ItemID
    where c.Name like '%myReportName%'
```

[image]

See here for more details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-executionlog-and-the-executionlog3-view?view=sql-server-ver15#bkmk_executionlog